# Tutorial 4 of SharePoint SPFx Tutorials: Error configuring web part to load from CDN

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

i have followed [HelloWorld, Deploy to CDN](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/HelloWorld,-Deploy-to-CDN) and until "Configuring web part to load from CDN" everything worked; i have updated the "cdnBasePath" in "write-manifests.json" as described, and continued with the tutorial. Yet i can't see the body of the webpart after deployment, and since i verified that the files have been deployed to the CDN i took a look at the HTML - and i noticed

```
.."componentType":"WebPart","loaderConfig":{"internalModuleBaseUrls":["<!-- PATH TO CDN -->/"]..
```

so apparently my change of the "write-manifests.json" did not work out.
Where can i look to find out how that happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem, and fixed it by running the

```
gulp --ship
```

command after I changed the "write-manifests.json" file.

(The tutorial at [HelloWorld, Deploy to CDN](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/HelloWorld,-Deploy-to-CDN) does not run that command after changing the "write-manifests.json" file)

Answer (score 3):

You can check in /temp/deploy/{GUID}.json which will be the working version that gets used by the packager.

Search for internalModuleBaseUrls.

It will also be in /solution/debug/{GUID}/Webpart_{GUID}.xml which is the packaged version you deploy.

{GUID} is your 'magic' guid associated with the web part you can find it in your /src/webParts/{WebPartName}/{WebPartName}.manifest.json file.

Just a thought did you run Step 4 Prepare assets to deploy?

```
gulp --ship
```